# Firebase addValueEventListener sometimes returns a null DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase

My Android app makes use of the Firebase JAVA API which functions very well.   However, I have noticed recently that on occasion I am getting a null value returned in the datasnapshot with this code.

```
 public void startLeaderboardListener (final String roundID) {
    myClubFirebaseRef.child("/rounds/" + roundID + "/scores/users/").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            JSONArray usersJSONArray = new JSONArray();
            //ToDo : BUG : Returned a null object reference here
            Map<String, JSONObject> usersMap = (HashMap<String, JSONObject>) snapshot.getValue();
            JSONObject usersJSON = new JSONObject(usersMap);
            if (usersMap != null) try {
                Iterator x = usersJSON.keys();
                while (x.hasNext()) {
                    String thisUSerID = (String) x.next();
                    usersJSONArray.put(usersJSON.get(thisUSerID));

                    JSONObject thisUserJSON = usersJSON.getJSONObject(thisUSerID);
                    SQLiteRounds db = new SQLiteRounds(myContext);
                    JSONObject thisUserStatusJSON = thisUserJSON.getJSONObject("status");
                    JSONArray thisUserDataJSON = thisUserJSON.getJSONArray("data");
                    db.updateLocalRoundwithScores(thisUSerID, roundID, thisUserStatusJSON, thisUserDataJSON);
                }
                myScoreListener.onScoreUpdated(usersJSONArray);

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e ("CloudArchery", "Error extracting JSON Data from User Update (ClubFirebase.startLeaderboard");
            }
        }//StartLeaderboard

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("CloudArchery", "The read failed (ClubFirebase.startLeaderboard) : " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }

    });
} //startLeaderboardListene
```

Comment: That sounds like expected behavior to me. What's your question?

Comment: Me too having the same problem. I checked the details of the snapshot returned. It says empty node for node value.

Comment: The issue is that the snapshot passed to onDataChange is SOMETIMES null, even though there is data in the firebase at /rounds/:roundid/scores/users.   The function above is monitoring the data for changes.  Should never return null as there is always data present.  Could it be that the snapshot is temporarily null while another app or process is updating that branch of the Firebase?

Comment: Is this issues fixed> If so, how? I'm seeing similar behavior in Firebase 9.6.1. The Firebase console shows the node but when I query the node, it is *sometimes* null... @frank-van-puffelen Is this a known issue? It also happens only for *some* nodes on the same branch. Other nodes on that same branch *can* be queried.